# Printing a concatenation of string using Formatter issue in java

Tags: java, string, formatter

Can someone explain this result to me and what is the best approach to do the same?:

```
public class Test {

    public static String test() {
        Formatter fmt = new Formatter();  
        String a = fmt.format("%1s %28d", "Subtotal", 400)+"\n";
        String b =        fmt.format("%1s %28d", "IVA 21%", 55)+"\n";
        String c =  fmt.format("%1s %28d", "TOTAL", 555)+"\n";
        return a+b+c;
    }
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        System.out.println(test());
}
}
```

---

Outcome

```
Subtotal                          400
Subtotal                          400IVA 21%                           55
Subtotal                          400IVA 21%                           55TOTAL                    555
```

---

what i was expacting is this:

```
Subtotal    400
IVA 21%     55
TOTAL       555
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format the entire resulting string in one go, since you need it to look as you see fit as a whole (*if you're not using `a`, `b`, `c` parts separately*).

```
String result = String.format(
     "%s %3d %12s %3d %10s %3d %n",
     "Subtotal", 400, "IVA 21%", 55, "TOTAL", 555
);
    
System.out.println(result);
```

*Output:*

```
Subtotal 400      IVA 21%  55      TOTAL 555
```